Are there standard methods for joining a numerical function approximation to its asymptotic behavior?
I'm working on an algorithm for computing a function that is a generalization of the Voigt profile. The Voigt profile is the convolution of a Cauchy (aka Lorentzian) probability density function (PDF) with a Gaussian or normal PDF. Near its peak, the Gaussian behavior dominates. Far from the peak, the Cauchy behavior dominates, so asymptotically the function falls off like $1/x^2$. My generalization handles various asymmetric and skew alternatives to the normal part. The asymptotic behavior will still be dominated by the Cauchy factor in the convolution.
I have to evaluate the function over large domains, with most of the region in the asymptotic regime. To speed up the algorithm, I'd like to join the quadrature-based calculation near the peak to the asymptotic behavior in a smooth way. I'd like to know if there are any standard methods or tricks for doing this. A simple approach could be to define a transition interval where the mismatch between the asymptotic behavior and the more accurate quadrature result is small, and smoothly move from the quadrature result to the asymptotic result, e.g., by linearly weighting between them over that interval, with the asymptotic behavior taking over beyond the transition interval.
Is there a smarter way to do this? Is there a term of art for this kind of thing that I could use to find other candidate approaches in the literature?
